# An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied but works on my system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am stucking trying to upload images to aws s3 using the boto3 library from my flask app running on an ec2 instance with the following s3 policy attached to the Instance role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketTagging",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                "s3:GetBucketPolicy",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/users/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This works from my computer but fails when uploaded to the flask app running on the ec2 instance. I get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

This is the flask code used to carryout this upload:

```
class S3ImageBucketManagement:
    S3_LOCATION = 'http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format('bucket-name')

    def __init__(self, bucket_name: str, bucket_region: str, _id: str, image_type: str, acl: str = "public-read"):
        self._client = self.__s3_resource().Bucket(bucket_name)
        self._image_type = image_type
        self._bucket_name = bucket_name
        self._bucket_region = bucket_region
        self._id = _id
        self._acl = acl

    def __s3_resource(self):
        """
        Creates the boto3 client
        :return: boto3.client
        """
        session = boto3.Session()
        res = None
        try:
            res = session.resource(
                service_name='s3',
                region_name='eu-west-2'
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'Error: {e}')
        return res

    def upload_file_to_s3(self, file: FileStorage, upload_folder: str):
        try:
            res = self._client
            res.put_object(
                Body=file,
                Bucket=self._bucket_name,
                Key=f"{self._image_type}/{file.filename}",
                ACL=self._acl,
                ContentType=file.content_type,
            )

            # res.upload_file(
            #     Filename=f"/tmp/{file.filename}",
            #     Key=f"{self._image_type}/{file.filename}",
            #     ExtraArgs={
            #         "ACL": self._acl,
            #         "ContentType": file.content_type
            #     }
            # )
         except Exception as e:
            current_app.logger.error(f'upload_file_to_s3 function error: {e}')
            return False, 'File upload failed', 500
         return True, "{}{}/{}".format(self.S3_LOCATION, self._image_type, file.filename), 200
```

I don't know what I am missing in the permissions, and why this works on my system but not on the server.

Comment: Please make sure you do not have any pre-existing .aws profile on the instance.

Comment: Does the bucket have a resource policy?

Comment: @Paolo no it does not

Comment: @marcin no it doesn't. It has only the Instance role that has the above policy attached

Comment: Why are you trying to use environment variables? Try getting rid of those two lines

Comment: @paolo I added them as I was trying to figure out what the issue was

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen that code is a bit messed up. You have a Bucket resource object and you are naming it '_client'. S3 client and S3 resource have the same 'put_object' method but resource object does not need the Bucket, because you are already operating on Bucket object. Client does need it. It seems like you are using client method on resource object to me.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen funny thing is, resource object is not complaining when you pass the Bucket again, in any case I would expect a different error. Your policy looks fine, but if the actual bucket passed to the code is not listed in the resources section, that would explain the permission response.  There is a mismatch somewhere there.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen - Great! I will write it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy looks fine. You have both of the required actions

```
s3:PutObject
s3:PutObjectACL
```

and listing the buckets in the correct way.
However, python implementation is a bit problematic. AWS python SDK provides two interfaces: a [client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client) and a [resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource).

Client interface is very close to API and you receive back a json as a response if the action returns one.

Resource interface is pythonic, it is higher level and returns an object that you can work with.

In the code above, you initiate a resource from Session

```
res = session.resource(
            service_name='s3',
            region_name='eu-west-2'
        )
```

However, when trying to upload, syntax is using the client syntax instead of resource syntax.
If you wanted to use [client's put_object method](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), then you should initiate a client from session.